# Using Django ORM for computed field

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a scoreboard for a web app.  Each user post is worth 10 points, and each user comment is worth 1 point.  I want to sort by highest score first.  So with raw SQL, it would be:

```sql
select username, email,
    ( select 10 * count(*) from posts_post where accounts_customuser.id = posts_post.author_id ) +
    ( select count(*) from posts_comment where accounts_customuser.id = posts_comment.author_id ) total 
    from accounts_customuser
    order by total desc, username;
```

Of course, the idea with Django is to leverage the ORM and avoid raw SQL.  I see there are aggregates, so it's close to something like this:

```py
queryset = get_user_model().objects.annotate(post_count=Count('posts'),
           comment_count=Count('comment')).order_by('-post_count', '-comment_count', 'username')
```

However, that's not quite right because if I have a user with 1 post and 1 comment (11 points) and then one with 0 posts and 12 comments (12 points), they wouldn't be sorted right by the ORM with the above QuerySet.  I tried leveraging F:

```py
# Note:  CustomUser is what get_user_model() returns
CustomUser.objects.annotate(post_count=Count('posts'), comment_count=Count('comment'),
        total=Sum(F('post_count') * 10 + F('comment_count'))
    ).order_by('-post_count', '-comment_count', 'username')
```

However, that throws the following error:

```py
FieldError: Cannot compute Sum('<CombinedExpression: F(post_count) * Value(10) +
    F(comment_count)>'): '<CombinedExpression: F(post_count) * Value(10) + 
    F(comment_count)>' is an aggregate
```

I'm not sure where to go from here.  Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got [the answer from KenWhitesell on the Django forums](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/using-django-orm-for-computed-field/7970/2):

Apparently using Sum was a mistake as my aggregates are singular values, so the solution is:

```py
CustomUser.objects.annotate(
    post_count=Count('posts'), 
    comment_count=Count('comment'),
    total=F('post_count') * 10 + F('comment_count')
).order_by('-post_count', '-comment_count', 'username')
```